# Different approaches of find $P(X+Y>1/2)$ yielding different results

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following question:

> Let X denote the diameter of an armored electric cable and Y denote
> the diameter of the ceramic mold that makes the cable. Both X and Y
> are scaled so that they range between 0 and 1. Suppose that X and Y
> have the joint density
> $f(x,y)= (1/y), 0<x<y<1$
> $=0,$ elsewhere.
> Find $P(X+Y >1/2)$.

Approach by the solution manual:
$P(X+Y >1/2)=1-P(X+Y<1/2)$ then they continued accordingly and got $0.6534$

I have no issues with this approach, my problem is that I am following the more "direct" approach of directly computing $P(X+Y>1/2)$ and getting $0.5$ instead.

My solution:

First, I have the following graph:
[image]

For a more interactive view, you can check the Desmos link [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a6edcorckh)

The orange area is my region of integration, I decided to integrate from the $y$ direction first while dividing my region into 2 parts to have 2 parts with one single entry and exit each, I divided it using a vertical line passing through the tip of the triangular shape at the bottom, this yields two double integrals:

$\int_0^{1/4}\int_{1/2-x}^1 (1/y)dydx$ and $\int_{1/4}^{1}\int_{x}^1 (1/y)dydx$

Each of these integrals is equal to $1/4$ (done on WolframAlpha, so there should be no error in this part) which makes them sum to $1/2$

Before posting this I reviewed the given, the graph, and my integral set-up multiple times and couldn't find a mistake, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that
$$\int_0^{1/4}\int_{1/2-x}^1\frac1y\,dy\,dx=\frac14$$
but
$$\int_{1/4}^1\int_x^1\frac1y\,dy\,dx=-\int_{1/4}^1\ln x\,dx=[x-x\ln x]_{1/4}^1=\frac14(3-\ln4)$$
Hence $P(X+Y>1/2)=1-\frac{\ln4}4=1-\frac{\ln2}2$. Don't trust Wolfram Alpha to parse your input correctly!

Comment: Lesson learned! Thanks.